# Why is scipy multivariate_normal pdf ufunc not working?

Tags: python-2.7, statistics, scipy

Why doesn't this code run for `nsamples=3`? It runs for `nsamples in (1,2)`.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

mean = np.array([0,0])
covar = np.array([[1,0],[0,4]])
rv = multivariate_normal(mean, covar)

nsamples = 3
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nsamples)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, nsamples)
state = np.meshgrid(x, y)
print state
rv.logpdf(state)
```

Here's the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-595249b070ac> in <module>()
      4 state = np.meshgrid(x, y)
      5 print state
----> 6 rv.logpdf(state)

/appl/pm/vendor/dev/python/lx-x86_64/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.pyc in logpdf(self, x)
    518         x = _process_quantiles(x, self.dim)
    519         out = self._mnorm._logpdf(x, self.mean, self.cov_info.U,
--> 520                                   self.cov_info.log_pdet, self.cov_info.rank)
    521         return _squeeze_output(out)
    522 

/appl/pm/vendor/dev/python/lx-x86_64/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.pyc in _logpdf(self, x, mean, prec_U, log_det_cov, rank)
    377 
    378         """
--> 379         dev = x - mean
    380         maha = np.sum(np.square(np.dot(dev, prec_U)), axis=-1)
    381         return -0.5 * (rank * _LOG_2PI + log_det_cov + maha)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3,3) (2,)
```

Seems like there's a bug in the library: I think either `x` needs to roll an axis or `mean` needs to be reshaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.meshgrid` returns a tuple of 2D arrays:

```
In [124]: np.meshgrid(x, y)
Out[124]: 
[array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.]]), array([[-2., -2., -2.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])]
```

`rv.logpdf` expects an list of 2-tuples, or an array whose last axis has length 2:

```
In [128]: state
Out[128]: 
array([[-1., -2.],
       [-1.,  0.],
       [-1.,  2.],
       [ 0., -2.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 1., -2.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])

In [129]: rv.logpdf(state)
Out[129]: 
array([-3.53102425, -3.03102425, -3.53102425, -3.03102425, -2.53102425,
       -3.03102425, -3.53102425, -3.03102425, -3.53102425])

In [131]: rv.logpdf(state.reshape(3,3,-1))
Out[131]: 
array([[-3.53102425, -3.03102425, -3.53102425],
       [-3.03102425, -2.53102425, -3.03102425],
       [-3.53102425, -3.03102425, -3.53102425]])
```

---

So instead of `np.meshgrid` you could use `itertools.product`:

```
state = np.array(list(IT.product(x, y)))
```

or, for better speed when `x` and `y` are large, use [pv's cartesian function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/190597).

---

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np
import itertools as IT

mean = np.array([0,0])
covar = np.array([[1,0],[0,4]])
rv = multivariate_normal(mean, covar)

nsamples = 3
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nsamples)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, nsamples)
state = np.array(list(IT.product(x, y)))
logpdf = rv.logpdf(state.reshape(nsamples, nsamples, -1))
print(logpdf)
```

yields

```
[[-3.53102425 -3.03102425 -3.53102425]
 [-3.03102425 -2.53102425 -3.03102425]
 [-3.53102425 -3.03102425 -3.53102425]]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That saves me a lot of time!