# Python Itertools.product speed up

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

AI have multiple arrays I'm putting into the `itertools.product()`.

Array lengths:

```
A - 108
B - 126
C - 5
D - 8
E  -8
```

It takes me a good few minutes to process the arrays and I was wondering if there's another way to speed it up.

```
total = 0
maxPoints = 0

for combination in itertools.product(A, B, C, D, E):
currentTotal  = int(combination[0][1]) + int(combination[1][0][1]) + int(combination[1][1][1]) + int(combination[1][2][1]) +int(combination[2][0][1]) + int(combination[2][1][1])  + int(combination[2][2][1])  + int(combination[1][0][1])  + int(combination[1][1][1])
if currentTotal < 50000:
    pointTotal  = float(combination[0][2]) + float(combination[1][0][2]) + float(combination[1][1][2]) + float(combination[1][2][2]) + float(combination[2][0][2]) + float(combination[2][1][2])  + float(combination[2][2][2]) +  float(combination[1][0][2]) + float(combination[1][1][2])
    if currentTotal >= total:
        if pointTotal > maxPoints:
            total = currentTotal
            maxPoints = currentPoints
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code under PyPy?

Comment: Just as a side note. If you're solving task from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) or similar website - the best way is to find good algorithm and not to optimize brute forcing code.

Comment: @Alex technically just installed Pypy after you mentioned it and it looks like I need to find a solution for mysql.connector.  Pypy might be a last resort if I have to modify my code to adapt to it.

Comment: @Yaroslav Project Euler looks interesting.  I'll bookmark it for later.

Comment: The code you show never uses the values from the `D` or `E` lists, so you can probably leave them out of your `product` call to reduce the amount of work by a 64 times.

Comment: In addition to omitting `D` and `E`, unpacking the result from itertools.product in the loop automatically (`for a, b, c in itertools.product(...)`) will reduce indexing overhead, and pre-converting the appropriate values in `A`, `B` and `C` to `int` and `float` rather than live on each loop iteration should save a lot of redundant work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to optimize that any further using just pure python code.

For any serious number crunching I would suggest using numpy.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) is a cartersian product implementation in numpy that you can use: