# Numpy/Python: Efficient matrix as multiplication of cartesian product of input matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Problem:

The input is a (i,j)-matrix M. The desired output is a (i^n,j^n) matrix K , where n is the number of products taken. The verbose way to get the desired output is as follows

- Generate all arrays of n row permutations I (total of i**n n-arrays)
- Generate all arrays of n column permutations J (total of j**n n-arrays)
- K[i,j] = m[I[0],J[0]] * ... * m[I[n],J[n]] for all n in range(len(J))

The straightforward way I've done this is by generating a list of labels of all n-permutations of numbers in range(len(np.shape(m)[0])) and range(len(np.shape(m)[1])) for rows and columns, respectively. Afterwards you can multiply them as in the last bullet point above. This, however, is not practical for large input matrices -- so I'm looking for ways to optimize the above. Thank you in advance

Example:

Input

> np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

Output for n = 3

> [[   1.    2.    3.    2.    4.    6.    3.    6.    9.    2.    4.    6.
>        4.    8.   12.    6.   12.   18.    3.    6.    9.    6.   12.   18.
>        9.   18.   27.]
>
> [   4.    5.    6.    8.   10.   12.   12.   15.   18.    8.   10.   12.
>       16.   20.   24.   24.   30.   36.   12.   15.   18.   24.   30.   36.
>       36.   45.   54.]
>
> [   4.    8.   12.    5.   10.   15.    6.   12.   18.    8.   16.   24.
>       10.   20.   30.   12.   24.   36.   12.   24.   36.   15.   30.   45.
>       18.   36.   54.]
>
> [  16.   20.   24.   20.   25.   30.   24.   30.   36.   32.   40.   48.
>       40.   50.   60.   48.   60.   72.   48.   60.   72.   60.   75.   90.
>       72.   90.  108.]
>
> [   4.    8.   12.    8.   16.   24.   12.   24.   36.    5.   10.   15.
>       10.   20.   30.   15.   30.   45.    6.   12.   18.   12.   24.   36.
>       18.   36.   54.]
>
> [  16.   20.   24.   32.   40.   48.   48.   60.   72.   20.   25.   30.
>       40.   50.   60.   60.   75.   90.   24.   30.   36.   48.   60.   72.
>       72.   90.  108.]
>
> [  16.   32.   48.   20.   40.   60.   24.   48.   72.   20.   40.   60.
>       25.   50.   75.   30.   60.   90.   24.   48.   72.   30.   60.   90.
>       36.   72.  108.]
>
> [  64.   80.   96.   80.  100.  120.   96.  120.  144.   80.  100.  120.
>      100.  125.  150.  120.  150.  180.   96.  120.  144.  120.  150.  180.
>      144.  180.  216.]]

Partial solution:

The best I've found is a function to create the cartesian product of matrices proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/4003747
The problem is that the output is not a matrix but an array of arrays. Multiplying the element of each array gives the values I'm after, but in an unordered fashion. I've tried for a while but I have no idea how to sensibly reorder them.

Inefficient solution for n =3:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

m=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

def f(m):
    labels_i = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(np.shape(m)[0]),repeat=3)]
    labels_j = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(np.shape(m)[1]),repeat=3)]


    out = np.zeros([len(labels_i),len(labels_j)])
    for i in range(len(labels_i)):
        for j in range(len(labels_j)):
            out[i,j] = m[labels_i[i][0],labels_j[j][0]] * m[labels_i[i][1],labels_j[j][1]] * m[labels_i[i][2],labels_j[j][2]]
    return out
```

Comment: If you have implemented an *inefficient* version, add into the question?

Comment: Sorry about that. Done.

Comment: So, for `n = 4`, you need to add `* m[labels_i[i][3],labels_j[j][3]]` there, right? And so on for higher `n` I am guessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using a combination of [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -

```
from itertools import product

# Get input array's shape
r,c = A.shape

# Setup arrays corresponding to labels i and j
arr_i = np.array(list(product(range(r), repeat=n)))
arr_j = np.array(list(product(range(c), repeat=n)))

# Use linear indexing with ".ravel()" to extract elements.
# Perform elementwise product along the rows for the final output
out = A.ravel()[(arr_i*c)[:,None,:] + arr_j].prod(2)
```

Runtime test and output verification -

```
In [167]: # Inputs          
     ...: n = 4
     ...: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
     ...: 
     ...: def f(m):
     ...:   labels_i = [list(p) for p in product(range(np.shape(m)[0]),repeat=n)]
     ...:   labels_j = [list(p) for p in product(range(np.shape(m)[1]),repeat=n)]
     ...: 
     ...:   out = np.zeros([len(labels_i),len(labels_j)])
     ...:   for i in range(len(labels_i)):
     ...:      for j in range(len(labels_j)):
     ...:          out[i,j] = m[labels_i[i][0],labels_j[j][0]] \
     ...:                   * m[labels_i[i][1],labels_j[j][1]] \
     ...:                   * m[labels_i[i][2],labels_j[j][2]] \
     ...:                   * m[labels_i[i][3],labels_j[j][3]]
     ...:   return out
     ...: 
     ...: def f_vectorized(A,n):
     ...:   r,c = A.shape
     ...:   arr_i = np.array(list(product(range(r), repeat=n)))
     ...:   arr_j = np.array(list(product(range(c), repeat=n)))
     ...:   return A.ravel()[(arr_i*c)[:,None,:] + arr_j].prod(2)
     ...: 

In [168]: np.allclose(f_vectorized(A,n),f(A))
Out[168]: True

In [169]: %timeit f(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.37 ms per loop

In [170]: %timeit f_vectorized(A,n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

m=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
n=3 # change your n here


def f(m):
    labels_i = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(np.shape(m)[0]),repeat=n)]
    labels_j = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(np.shape(m)[1]),repeat=n)]


    out = np.zeros([len(labels_i),len(labels_j)])
    for i in range(len(labels_i)):
        for j in range(len(labels_j)):
            out[i,j] = np.prod([m[labels_i[i][k],labels_j[j][k]] for k in range(n)])
    return out
```