# Get matrix of all combinations of function evaluations

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a Python function of two arguments, `f(x,y)`, which returns a scalar. I also have two `np.array`s of possible arguments, `xs` and `ys`. I'd like to compute a two-dimensional numpy array of shape `(xs.size, ys.size)` which holds values of `f` evaluated at all combinations of arguments drawn from `xs` and `ys`. The result should be equal to

```
np.array([[f(x,y) for y in ys] for x in xs])
```

I would like to achieve this as efficiently as possible and take advantage from multiple processor cores. `f` does not have any side-effect. I tried to use `numpy.vectorize` but did not manage to use it to the desired effect. E.g. `numpy.outer` does exactly what I want for the special case of `f=operator.__mul__`.

As an additional caveat, though potentially not immediately relevant, one of the array, say `ys`, does not contain numbers but objects as returned by `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`. The function `f` calculates a definite integral via `scipy.integrate.quad` of these interpolations. The resulting matrix still only contains numbers.

Comment: may be you can improve the performance a bit by removing the nest loops. For instance calculate the Cartesian product of `xs` and `ys` and then calculate `f` going through each one at a time. Here is a code for Cartesian product (see the accepted answer) which is fast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays

Comment: It seems the object returned by `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` can't be pickled and that poses problems for using the `multiprocessing` module...

Comment: You'll probably get better responses if you change the headline of this question.  The question is about multiprocessing, not combinations.

Comment: Depending on what `f` does, you may be much better off modifying it to accept vectors of `x` and `y` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming f is a python function, use `numpy.frompyfunc()` with `.outer()`

```
np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1).outer(xs, ys)
```