# Generating a numpy array with all combinations of numbers that sum to less than a given number

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

There are several elegant examples of using numpy in Python to generate arrays of all combinations. For example the answer here: [Using numpy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) .

Now suppose there is an extra constraint, namely, the sum of all numbers cannot add up to more than a given constant `K`. Using a generator and `itertools.product`, for an example with `K=3` where we want the combinations of three variables with ranges 0-1,0-3, and 0-2 we can do it a follows:

```
from itertools import product
K = 3
maxRange = np.array([1,3,2])
states = np.array([i for i in product(*(range(i+1) for i in maxRange)) if sum(i)<=K])
```

which returns

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

In principle, the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655090/1479342 can be used to generate all possible combinations without the constraint and then selecting the subset of combinations that sum up to less than `K`. However, that approach generates much more combinations than necessary, especially if `K` is relatively small compared to `sum(maxRange)`.

There must be a way to do this faster and with lower memory usage. How can this be achieved using a vectorized approach (for example using `np.indices`)?

Comment: Technically, these are subsets of a (multi)set, not combinations.

Comment: Is it always the case that the range of possible values in position k will be 0..Nk, or does the solution need to consider arbitrary sets of possible values in each position?

Comment: @cxrodgers A solution for the situation with 0...Nk would be great. A solution where the ranges of `k` will be `np.arange(minRange[k],maxRange[k]+1)` would be even better, but that can be derived straightforwardly from the first solution if I'm not mistaken. With arbitrary sets this would be complicated since there is little structure that can be exploited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edited**

1. For completeness, I'm adding here the OP's code:

   ```
   def partition0(max_range, S):
       K = len(max_range)
       return np.array([i for i in itertools.product(*(range(i+1) for i in max_range)) if sum(i)<=S])
   ```
2. The first approach is pure `np.indices`. It's fast for small input but consumes a lot of memory (OP already pointed out it's not what he meant).

   ```
   def partition1(max_range, S):
       max_range = np.asarray(max_range, dtype = int)
       a = np.indices(max_range + 1)
       b = a.sum(axis = 0) <= S
       return (a[:,b].T)
   ```
3. Recurrent approach seems to be much better than those above:

   ```
   def partition2(max_range, max_sum):
       max_range = np.asarray(max_range, dtype = int).ravel()        
       if(max_range.size == 1):
           return np.arange(min(max_range[0],max_sum) + 1, dtype = int).reshape(-1,1)
       P = partition2(max_range[1:], max_sum)
       # S[i] is the largest summand we can place in front of P[i]            
       S = np.minimum(max_sum - P.sum(axis = 1), max_range[0])
       offset, sz = 0, S.size
       out = np.empty(shape = (sz + S.sum(), P.shape[1]+1), dtype = int)
       out[:sz,0] = 0
       out[:sz,1:] = P
       for i in range(1, max_range[0]+1):
           ind, = np.nonzero(S)
           offset, sz = offset + sz, ind.size
           out[offset:offset+sz, 0] = i
           out[offset:offset+sz, 1:] = P[ind]
           S[ind] -= 1
       return out
   ```
4. After a short thought, I was able to take it a bit further. If we know in advance the number of possible partitions, we can allocate enough memory at once. (It's somewhat similar to `cartesian` in [an already linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/5717589).)

   First, we need a function which counts partitions.

   ```
   def number_of_partitions(max_range, max_sum):
       '''
       Returns an array arr of the same shape as max_range, where
       arr[j] = number of admissible partitions for 
                j summands bounded by max_range[j:] and with sum <= max_sum
       '''
       M = max_sum + 1
       N = len(max_range) 
       arr = np.zeros(shape=(M,N), dtype = int)    
       arr[:,-1] = np.where(np.arange(M) <= min(max_range[-1], max_sum), 1, 0)
       for i in range(N-2,-1,-1):
           for j in range(max_range[i]+1):
               arr[j:,i] += arr[:M-j,i+1] 
       return arr.sum(axis = 0)
   ```

   The main function:

   ```
   def partition3(max_range, max_sum, out = None, n_part = None):
       if out is None:
           max_range = np.asarray(max_range, dtype = int).ravel()
           n_part = number_of_partitions(max_range, max_sum)
           out = np.zeros(shape = (n_part[0], max_range.size), dtype = int)

       if(max_range.size == 1):
           out[:] = np.arange(min(max_range[0],max_sum) + 1, dtype = int).reshape(-1,1)
           return out

       P = partition3(max_range[1:], max_sum, out=out[:n_part[1],1:], n_part = n_part[1:])        
       # P is now a useful reference

       S = np.minimum(max_sum - P.sum(axis = 1), max_range[0])
       offset, sz  = 0, S.size
       out[:sz,0] = 0
       for i in range(1, max_range[0]+1):
           ind, = np.nonzero(S)
           offset, sz = offset + sz, ind.size
           out[offset:offset+sz, 0] = i
           out[offset:offset+sz, 1:] = P[ind]
           S[ind] -= 1
       return out
   ```
5. Some tests:

   ```
   max_range = [3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6]
   for f in [partition0, partition1, partition2, partition3]:
       print(f.__name__ + ':')
       for max_sum in [5, 15, 25]:
           print('Sum %2d: ' % max_sum, end = '')
           %timeit f(max_range, max_sum)
       print()

   partition0:
   Sum  5: 1 loops, best of 3: 859 ms per loop
   Sum 15: 1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop
   Sum 25: 1 loops, best of 3: 3.18 s per loop

   partition1:
   Sum  5: 10 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop
   Sum 15: 1 loops, best of 3: 224 ms per loop
   Sum 25: 1 loops, best of 3: 403 ms per loop

   partition2:
   Sum  5: 1000 loops, best of 3: 809 µs per loop
   Sum 15: 10 loops, best of 3: 62.5 ms per loop
   Sum 25: 1 loops, best of 3: 262 ms per loop

   partition3:
   Sum  5: 1000 loops, best of 3: 853 µs per loop
   Sum 15: 10 loops, best of 3: 59.1 ms per loop
   Sum 25: 1 loops, best of 3: 249 ms per loop
   ```

   And something larger:

   ```
   %timeit partition0([3,6] * 5, 20)
   1 loops, best of 3: 11.9 s per loop

   %timeit partition1([3,6] * 5, 20)
   The slowest run took 12.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
   1 loops, best of 3: 2.33 s per loop
   # MemoryError in another test

   %timeit partition2([3,6] * 5, 20)
   1 loops, best of 3: 877 ms per loop

   %timeit partition3([3,6] * 5, 20)
   1 loops, best of 3: 739 ms per loop
   ```

Comment: This was actually the approach I referred to in the original question, that I thought wouldn't be appropriate due to its memory consumption.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood your words about `np.indices`. I'll try to find something more useful or I'll later delete this answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. I can add some tests later.

Comment: I think you wrote partition3 somewhere where you meant partition4. I proposed an edit with an updated numbering.

Comment: @Forzaa Thanks for spotting this - unintended reference to an old function. I added another improvement, changed numbering and updated test results.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what's a `numpy` approach, but here's a reasonably clean solution. Let `A` be an array of integers and let `k` be a number that you are given as input.

Start with an empty array `B`; keep the sum of the array `B` in a variable `s` (initially set to zero). Apply the following procedure:

- **if** the sum `s` of the array `B` is less than `k`, **then** (i) add it to the collection, (ii) and for each element from the original array `A`, add that element to `B` and update `s`, (iii) delete it from `A` and (iv) recursively apply the procedure; (iv) when the call returns, add the element back to `A` and update `s`; **else** do nothing.

This bottom-up approach prunes invalid branches early on and only visits the necessary subsets (i.e. almost only the subsets that sum to less than `k`).

Comment: This approach indeed works. In a language like C++ this is probably one of the fastest ways to do it. However, in Python best performance is typically reached by using vectorized code. I don't know how to do that with your approach.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you meant by the numpy approach. Would you mind if I leave the answer? I think it's still useful.