# Using Numpy to generate random combinations of two arrays without repetition

Tags: python, numpy, random

Given two arrays, for example `[0,0,0]` and `[1,1,1]`, it is already clear (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays)) how to generate all the combinations, i.e., `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]`. `itertools` (`combinations` or `product`) and `numpy.meshgrid` are the most common ways as far as I know.

However, I could't find any discussions on how to generate this combinations randomly, without repetitions.

An easy solution could be to generate all the combinations and then choose some of them randomly. For example:

```
# Three random combinations of [0,0,0] and [1,1,1]
comb = np.array(np.meshgrid([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])).T.reshape(-1,3)
result = comb[np.random.choice(len(comb),3,replace=False),:]
```

However, this is infeasible when the number of combinations is too big.

Is there a way to generate random combinations without replacement in Python (possibly with Numpy) without generating all the combinations?

**EDIT**: You can notice in the accepted answer that we also got for free a technique to generate **random binary vectors without repetitions**, which is just a single line (described in the *Bonus Section*).

Comment: You can trade space for speed (to a certain extent): randomly choose each number in the combination and check if the combination has been already used. If it was, repeat the process. Keep track on used combinations (through a `set()`) and maximum number of combinations (to stop the generator when no more combinations can be generated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach without generating all combinations -

```
def unique_combs(A, N):
    # A : 2D Input array with each row representing one group
    # N : No. of combinations needed
    m,n = A.shape
    dec_idx = np.random.choice(2**m,N,replace=False)
    idx = ((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))!=0).astype(int)
    return  A[np.arange(m),idx]
```

Please note that this assumes we are dealing with equal number of elements per group.

**Explanation**

To give it a bit of explanation, let's say the groups are stored in a `2D` array -

```
In [44]: A
Out[44]: 
array([[4, 2],   <-- group #1
       [3, 5],   <-- group #2
       [8, 6]])  <-- group #3
```

We have two elems per group. Let's say we are looking for `4` unique group combinations : `N = 4`. To select from two numbers from each of those three groups, we would have a total of `8` unique combinations.

Let's generate `N` unique numbers in that interval of `8` using `np.random.choice(8, N, replace=False)` -

```
In [86]: dec_idx = np.random.choice(8,N,replace=False)

In [87]: dec_idx
Out[87]: array([2, 3, 7, 0])
```

Then, convert those to binary equivalents as later on we need those to index into each row of `A` -

```
In [88]: idx = ((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(3)))!=0).astype(int)

In [89]: idx
Out[89]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Finally, with fancy-indexing, we get those elems off `A` -

```
In [90]: A[np.arange(3),idx]
Out[90]: 
array([[4, 5, 8],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [2, 5, 6],
       [4, 3, 8]])
```

**Sample run**

```
In [80]: # Original code that generates all combs
    ...: comb = np.array(np.meshgrid([4,2],[3,5],[8,6])).T.reshape(-1,3)
    ...: result = comb[np.random.choice(len(comb),4,replace=False),:]
    ...: 

In [81]: A = np.array([[4,2],[3,5],[8,6]]) # 2D array of groups

In [82]: unique_combs(A, 3) # 3 combinations
Out[82]: 
array([[2, 3, 8],
       [4, 3, 6],
       [2, 3, 6]])

In [83]: unique_combs(A, 4) # 4 combinations
Out[83]: 
array([[2, 3, 8],
       [4, 3, 6],
       [2, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 8]])
```

---

**Bonus section**

Explanation on `((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))!=0).astype(int)` :

That step is basically converting decimal numbers to binary equivalents. Let's break it down to smaller steps for a closer look.

1) Input array of decimal numbers -

```
In [18]: dec_idx
Out[18]: array([7, 6, 4, 0])
```

2) Convert to 2D upon inserting new axis with `None/np.newaxis` -

```
In [19]: dec_idx[:,None]
Out[19]: 
array([[7],
       [6],
       [4],
       [0]])
```

3) Let's assume `m = 3`, i.e. we want to convert to 3 binary digit number equivalents.

We create `2-powered` range array with bit-shift operation -

```
In [16]: (1 << np.arange(m))
Out[16]: array([1, 2, 4])
```

Alternatively, an explicit way would be -

```
In [20]: 2**np.arange(m)
Out[20]: array([1, 2, 4])
```

4) Now, the crux of the cryptic step there. We perform [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) bitwise AND-ind between `2D` `dec_idx` and `2-powered` range array.

Consider the first element from `dec_idx` : `7`. We are performing bitiwse  AND-ing of `7` against `1`, `2`, `4`. Think of it as a filtering process, as we filter `7` at each binary interval of `1`, `2`, `4` as they represent the three binary digits. Similarly, we do this for all elems off `dec_idx` in a vectorized manner with `broadcasting`.

Thus, we would get the bit-wise AND-ing results like so -

```
In [43]: (dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))
Out[43]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

The filtered numbers thus obtained are either `0` or the `2-powered` range array numbers themselves. So, to have the binary equivalents, we just need to consider all non-zeros as `1s` and zeros as `0s`.

```
In [44]: ((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))!=0)
Out[44]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [45]: ((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(m)))!=0).astype(int)
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Thus, we have the binary numbers with MSBs to the right.

Comment: Is this method not generating combinations with replacement? Think the method needs to be without replacement?

Comment: @kezzos You were right, it was producing duplicates there. Thanks for pointing it out! Updated with a new approach.

Comment: Very nice! I think you should just elaborate a bit more on the line  `idx = ((dec_idx[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(3)))!=0).astype(int)` for the casual reader. Never thought about using bitwise comparisons to generate the indexes. Ingenious! What I was looking for was exactly that single line!

Comment: @Gioker Added few comments there, check it out!

Comment: @Divakar  Brilliant!