# Generator function (yield) much faster then iterator class (__next__)

Tags: performance, python-3.x, iterator, generator, yield

**UPDATE** (mirroring the state-of-the-art knowledge level) status: **2017-05-12**

The reason for this update is the fact that at the time I was asking this question I was not aware that I have discovered something about how  Python3 works "under the hood".

The conclusion from all what will follow is:

> **If you write own Python3 code for an iterator and care about speed of execution you should write it as a generator function and not as an iterator class.**

Below a minimalistic code example demonstrating that the same algorithm *(here: self-made version of Pythons `range()`)* expressed as a generator function runs much faster than if expressed as an iterator class:

```
def   gnrtYieldRange(startWith, endAt, step=1): 
    while startWith <= endAt: 
        yield startWith
        startWith += step
class iterClassRange:
    def __init__(self, startWith, endAt, step=1): 
        self.startWith = startWith - 1
        self.endAt     = endAt
        self.step      = step
    def __iter__(self): 
        return self
    def __next__(self): 
        self.startWith += self.step
        if self.startWith <= self.endAt:
            return self.startWith
        else:
            raise StopIteration

N = 10000000
print("    Size of created list N = {} elements (ints 1 to N)".format(N))

from time import time as t
from customRange import gnrtYieldRange as cthnYieldRange
from customRange import cintYieldRange
from customRange import iterClassRange as cthnClassRange
from customRange import cdefClassRange

iterPythnRangeObj =          range(1, N+1)
gnrtYieldRangeObj = gnrtYieldRange(1, N)
cthnYieldRangeObj = cthnYieldRange(1, N)
cintYieldRangeObj = cintYieldRange(1, N)
iterClassRangeObj = iterClassRange(1, N)
cthnClassRangeObj = cthnClassRange(1, N)
cdefClassRangeObj = cdefClassRange(1, N)

sEXECs = [ 
    "liPR = list(iterPythnRangeObj)",
    "lgYR = list(gnrtYieldRangeObj)",
    "lcYR = list(cthnYieldRangeObj)",
    "liGR = list(cintYieldRangeObj)",
    "liCR = list(iterClassRangeObj)",
    "lcCR = list(cthnClassRangeObj)",
    "ldCR = list(cdefClassRangeObj)"
 ]

sCOMMENTs = [ 
    "Python3 own range(1, N+1) used here as reference for timings  ",
    "self-made range generator function using yield (run as it is) ",
    "self-made range (with yield) run from module created by Cython",
    "Cython-optimized self-made range (using yield) run from module",
    "self-made range as iterator class using __next__() and return ",
    "self-made range (using __next__) from module created by Cython",
    "Cython-optimized self-made range (using __next__) from module "
 ]

for idx, sEXEC in enumerate(sEXECs): 
    s=t();exec(sEXEC);e=t();print("{} takes: {:3.1f} sec.".format(sCOMMENTs[idx], e-s))
print("All created lists are equal:", all([liPR == lgYR, lgYR == lcYR, lcYR == liGR, liGR == liCR, liCR == lcCR, lcCR == ldCR]) )
print("Run on Linux Mint 18.1, used Cython.__version__ == '0.25.2'")
```

The code above put into a file and runned prints to stdout:

```
>python3.6 -u "gnrtFunction-fasterThan-iterClass_runMe.py"
    Size of created list N = 10000000 elements (ints 1 to N)
Python3 own range(1, N+1) used here as reference for timings   takes: 0.2 sec.
self-made range generator function using yield (run as it is)  takes: 1.1 sec.
self-made range (with yield) run from module created by Cython takes: 0.5 sec.
Cython-optimized self-made range (using yield) run from module takes: 0.3 sec.
self-made range as iterator class using __next__() and return  takes: 3.9 sec.
self-made range (using __next__) from module created by Cython takes: 3.3 sec.
Cython-optimized self-made range (using __next__) from module  takes: 0.2 sec.
All created lists are equal: True
Run on Linux Mint 18.1, used Cython.__version__ == '0.25.2'
>Exit code: 0
```

From the timings above you can see that the generator function variant of the self-made `range()` iterator runs faster than the iterator class variant and when no optimization of code is involved this behavior propagates also into C-code level of C-code created by [Cython](http://cython.org).

If you are curious why in detail it is that way you can read through the provided answer(s) or play yourself a bit with the provided code yourself.

Below the missing pieces of code necessary to run the code above:

`customRange.pyx` - the file Cython creates the `customRange` module from:

```
def gnrtYieldRange(startWith, endAt, step=1): 
    while startWith <= endAt: 
        yield startWith
        startWith += step

class iterClassRange:
    def __init__(self, startWith, endAt, step=1): 
        self.startWith = startWith - 1
        self.endAt     = endAt
        self.step      = step
    def __iter__(self): 
        return self
    def __next__(self): 
        self.startWith += self.step
        if self.startWith <= self.endAt:
            return self.startWith
        else:
            raise StopIteration

def cintYieldRange(int startWith, int endAt, int step=1): 
    while startWith <= endAt: 
        yield startWith
        startWith += step

cdef class cdefClassRange:
    cdef int startWith
    cdef int endAt
    cdef int step

    def __init__(self, int startWith, int endAt, int step=1): 
        self.startWith = startWith - 1
        self.endAt     = endAt
        self.step      = step
    def __iter__(self): 
        return self
    def __next__(self): 
        self.startWith += self.step
        if self.startWith <= self.endAt:
            return self.startWith
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

and the setup file `customRange-setup.py` used to create the Python `customRange` module:

```
import sys
sys.argv += ['build_ext',  '--inplace']

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build   import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'customRange',
  ext_modules = cythonize("customRange.pyx"),
)
```

---

---

Now some further information making it easier to understand the provided answer(s):

At the time I have asked this question I was busy with a quite complex
algorithm for generating unique combinations from a non-unique list available in form of a generator function using `yield`. My goal was to create a Python module written in C using this algorithm to make it run faster. For this purpose I have rewritten the generator function which used `yield` to an iterator class using `__next__()` and `return`. As I compared the speed of both variants of the algorithm I was surprised that the iterator class was two times slower than the generator function and I had (*wrongly*) assumed it has something to do with the way I have rewritten the algorithm (*you need to know this if you want to better understand what the answers here are about*) and had therefore

> **Originally asked how to make the iterator class version run at the same speed as the generator function and where the speed difference comes from?**.

**Below some more about the HISTORY of the question:**

In the below provided Python script code exactly the same algorithm for creating unique combinations from a non-unique list of elements was implemented using a Python `function` with `yield` and using a `class` with `__next__`. The code is ready to run after copy/paste, so you can see it for yourself what I am speaking about.

**The same phenomenon observed for pure Python code propagates into C code of a Python extension module created out of the script code by [Cython](http://cython.org), so it is not limited to Python level code because it doesn't vanish at the C code level.**

The question is:

> Where does the huge difference in speed of execution come from? 
>   Is there anything that can be done to get both code variants to run at comparable speed? Is there something went wrong with the class/next implementation compared to the function/yield variant? Both are to my knowledge exactly the same code ...

Here the code (tweaking the number in the highlighted line changes the level of uniqueness of elements in the list the combinations are generated from what has a huge impact on the running time):

```
def uniqCmboYieldIter(lstItems, lenCmbo):
    dctCounter = {}
    lenLstItems = len(lstItems)
    for idx in range(lenLstItems):
        item = lstItems[idx]
        if item in dctCounter.keys(): 
            dctCounter[item] += 1
        else: 
            dctCounter[item]  = 1
        #:if
    #:for     
    lstUniqs   = sorted(dctCounter.keys())
    lstCntRpts = [dctCounter[item] for item in lstUniqs]
    lenUniqs   = len(lstUniqs)
    cmboAsIdxUniqs = [None] * lenCmbo
    multiplicities = [0] * lenUniqs
    idxIntoCmbo, idxIntoUniqs = 0, 0

    while idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo and idxIntoUniqs != lenUniqs:
        count = min(lstCntRpts[idxIntoUniqs], lenCmbo-idxIntoCmbo)
        cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo : idxIntoCmbo + count] = [idxIntoUniqs] * count
        multiplicities[idxIntoUniqs] = count
        idxIntoCmbo  += count
        idxIntoUniqs += 1

    if idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo:
        return

    while True:
        yield tuple(lstUniqs[idxUniqs] for idxUniqs in cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        for idxIntoCmbo in reversed(range(lenCmbo)):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            y = x + 1

            if y < lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] < lstCntRpts[y]:
                break
        else:
            return

        for idxIntoCmbo in range(idxIntoCmbo, lenCmbo):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo] = y
            multiplicities[x] -= 1
            multiplicities[y] += 1
            # print("# multiplicities:", multiplicities)


            while y != lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] == lstCntRpts[y]:
                y += 1

            if y == lenUniqs:
                break


class uniqCmboClassIter:
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __iter__(self):
       return self

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, lstItems, lenCmbo):
        dctCounter = {}
        lenLstItems = len(lstItems)
        for idx in range(lenLstItems):
            item = lstItems[idx]
            if item in dctCounter.keys(): 
                dctCounter[item] += 1
            else: 
                dctCounter[item]  = 1
            #:if
        #:for     

        self.lstUniqs   = sorted(dctCounter.keys())
        self.lenUniqs   = len(self.lstUniqs)
        self.lstCntRpts = [dctCounter[item] for item in self.lstUniqs]

        self.lenCmbo        = lenCmbo
        self.cmboAsIdxUniqs = [None] * lenCmbo
        self.multiplicities = [0] * self.lenUniqs
        self.idxIntoCmbo, self.idxIntoUniqs = 0, 0

        while self.idxIntoCmbo != self.lenCmbo and self.idxIntoUniqs != self.lenUniqs:
            count = min(self.lstCntRpts[self.idxIntoUniqs], self.lenCmbo-self.idxIntoCmbo)
            self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo : self.idxIntoCmbo + count] = [self.idxIntoUniqs] * count
            self.multiplicities[self.idxIntoUniqs] = count
            self.idxIntoCmbo  += count
            self.idxIntoUniqs += 1
            # print("self.multiplicities:", self.multiplicities)
            # print("self.cmboAsIdxUniqs:", self.cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        if self.idxIntoCmbo != self.lenCmbo:
            return

        self.stopIteration = False
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

        return

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __next__(self):

        if self.stopIteration is True:
            raise StopIteration
            return

        nextCmbo = tuple(self.lstUniqs[idxUniqs] for idxUniqs in self.cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        for self.idxIntoCmbo in reversed(range(self.lenCmbo)):
            self.x = self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo]
            self.y = self.x + 1

            if self.y < self.lenUniqs and self.multiplicities[self.y] < self.lstCntRpts[self.y]:
                break
        else:
            self.stopIteration = True
            return nextCmbo

        for self.idxIntoCmbo in range(self.idxIntoCmbo, self.lenCmbo):
            self.x = self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo]
            self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo] = self.y
            self.multiplicities[self.x] -= 1
            self.multiplicities[self.y] += 1
            # print("# multiplicities:", multiplicities)


            while self.y != self.lenUniqs and self.multiplicities[self.y] == self.lstCntRpts[self.y]:
                self.y += 1

            if self.y == self.lenUniqs:
                break

        return nextCmbo

# ============================================================================================================================================
lstSize   = 48 # 48
```

> ```
> uniqLevel =  12 # (7 ~60% unique) higher level => more unique items in the generated list
> ```

```
aList = []
from random import randint
for _ in range(lstSize):
    aList.append( ( randint(1,uniqLevel), randint(1,uniqLevel) ) )
lenCmbo = 6
percUnique = 100.0 - 100.0*(lstSize-len(set(aList)))/lstSize
print("========================  lenCmbo:", lenCmbo, 
      "   sizeOfList:", len(aList), 
      "   noOfUniqueInList", len(set(aList)), 
      "   percUnique",  int(percUnique) ) 

import time
from itertools import combinations
# itertools.combinations
# ---
# def   uniqCmboYieldIter(lstItems, lenCmbo):
# class uniqCmboClassIter: def __init__(self, lstItems, lenCmbo):
# ---
start_time = time.time()
print("Combos:%9i"%len(list(combinations(aList, lenCmbo))), " ", end='')
duration = time.time() - start_time
print("print(len(list(     combinations(aList, lenCmbo)))):",  "{:9.5f}".format(duration), "seconds.")

start_time = time.time()
print("Combos:%9i"%len(list(uniqCmboYieldIter(aList, lenCmbo))), " ", end='')
duration = time.time() - start_time
print("print(len(list(uniqCmboYieldIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):",  "{:9.5f}".format(duration), "seconds.")

start_time = time.time()
print("Combos:%9i"%len(list(uniqCmboClassIter(aList, lenCmbo))), " ", end='')
duration = time.time() - start_time
print("print(len(list(uniqCmboClassIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):", "{:9.5f}".format(duration), "seconds.")
```

and the timings on my box:

```
>python3.6 -u "nonRecursiveUniqueCombos_Cg.py"
========================  lenCmbo: 6    sizeOfList: 48    noOfUniqueInList 32    percUnique 66
Combos: 12271512  print(len(list(     combinations(aList, lenCmbo)))):   2.04635 seconds.
Combos:  1296058  print(len(list(uniqCmboYieldIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):   3.25447 seconds.
Combos:  1296058  print(len(list(uniqCmboClassIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):   5.97371 seconds.
>Exit code: 0
  [2017-05-02_03:23]  207474 <-Chrs,Keys-> 1277194 OnSave(): '/home/claudio/CgMint18/_Cg.DIR/ClaudioOnline/at-stackoverflow/bySubject/uniqueCombinations/nonRecursiveUniqueCombos_Cg.py'
>python3.6 -u "nonRecursiveUniqueCombos_Cg.py"
========================  lenCmbo: 6    sizeOfList: 48    noOfUniqueInList 22    percUnique 45
Combos: 12271512  print(len(list(     combinations(aList, lenCmbo)))):   2.05199 seconds.
Combos:   191072  print(len(list(uniqCmboYieldIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):   0.47343 seconds.
Combos:   191072  print(len(list(uniqCmboClassIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):   0.89860 seconds.
>Exit code: 0
  [2017-05-02_03:23]  207476 <-Chrs,Keys-> 1277202 OnSave(): '/home/claudio/CgMint18/_Cg.DIR/ClaudioOnline/at-stackoverflow/bySubject/uniqueCombinations/nonRecursiveUniqueCombos_Cg.py'
>python3.6 -u "nonRecursiveUniqueCombos_Cg.py"
========================  lenCmbo: 6    sizeOfList: 48    noOfUniqueInList 43    percUnique 89
Combos: 12271512  print(len(list(     combinations(aList, lenCmbo)))):   2.17285 seconds.
Combos:  6560701  print(len(list(uniqCmboYieldIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):  16.72573 seconds.
Combos:  6560701  print(len(list(uniqCmboClassIter(aList, lenCmbo)))):  31.17714 seconds.
>Exit code: 0
```

**UPDATE (status 2017-05-07):**

> At the time of asking the question and offering a bounty it was not known to me that there is a way to easily create C code of an extension module for an iterator object out of Python script code using Cython and that such C code can be created also from an iterator function using `yield`.

Considering that the generated faster version of the C extension module is still not fast enough to compete with `itertools.combinations` it doesn't make much sense to dive deeply into knowing what exactly is causing the slowdown when using an iterator class compared to an iterator function and how to overcome this. It makes much more sense to find a way to speed up the faster version using Cython, especially because I am a total novice in writing Python extension modules failing to create a working code after hours and hours of intense focused work spend on tweaking existing C code of `itertools.combinations` with own modifications because of `Segmentation Fault` errors for which I was not able to grasp the reason of.

Currently I think that there is still room to speed up the by me used Cython code and no need to go the harder way of writing the C code myself.

Below Cython code that runs OK and for speed optimized Cython code which changes somehow (I can't currently see the reason for that) the way the algorithm works and produce therefore wrong results. The idea behind the Cython optimization was to use in Cython code Python/Cython arrays instead of a Python lists. Any hints how to get a faster running Python extension module out of the used algorithm in a for a novice "safe" way are welcome.

```
def subbags_by_loops_with_dict_counter(lstItems, int lenCmbo):

    dctCounter = {}
    cdef int lenLstItems = len(lstItems)
    cdef int idx = 0
    for idx in range(lenLstItems):
        item = lstItems[idx]
        if item in dctCounter.keys(): 
            dctCounter[item] += 1
        else: 
            dctCounter[item]  = 1
        #:if
    #:for     
    lstUniqs   = sorted(dctCounter.keys())
    lstCntRpts = [dctCounter[item] for item in lstUniqs]

    cdef int lenUniqs   = len(lstUniqs)

    cmboAsIdxUniqs = [None] * lenCmbo
    multiplicities = [0] * lenUniqs
    cdef int idxIntoCmbo
    cdef int idxIntoUniqs
    cdef int count        
    while idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo and idxIntoUniqs != lenUniqs:
        count = min(lstCntRpts[idxIntoUniqs], lenCmbo-idxIntoCmbo)
        cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo : idxIntoCmbo + count] = [idxIntoUniqs] * count
        multiplicities[idxIntoUniqs] = count
        idxIntoCmbo  += count
        idxIntoUniqs += 1

    if idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo:
        return

    cdef int x
    cdef int y
    while True:
        yield tuple(lstUniqs[idxUniqs] for idxUniqs in cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        for idxIntoCmbo in reversed(range(lenCmbo)):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            y = x + 1

            if y < lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] < lstCntRpts[y]:
                break
        else:
            return

        for idxIntoCmbo in range(idxIntoCmbo, lenCmbo):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo] = y
            multiplicities[x] -= 1
            multiplicities[y] += 1

            while y != lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] == lstCntRpts[y]:
                y += 1

            if y == lenUniqs:
                break
```

Below **OPTIMIZED CYTHON CODE which produces wrong results**:

```
def subbags_loops_dict_cython_optimized(lstItems, int lenCmbo):

    dctCounter = {}
    cdef int lenLstItems = len(lstItems)
    cdef int idx = 0
    for idx in range(lenLstItems):
        item = lstItems[idx]
        if item in dctCounter.keys(): 
            dctCounter[item] += 1
        else: 
            dctCounter[item]  = 1
        #:if
    #:for     
    lstUniqs   = sorted(dctCounter.keys())
    lstCntRpts = [dctCounter[item] for item in lstUniqs]

    cdef int lenUniqs   = len(lstUniqs)
    cdef array.array cmboAsIdxUniqs = array.array('i', [])
    array.resize(cmboAsIdxUniqs, lenCmbo)
    # cmboAsIdxUniqs = [None] * lenCmbo 
    cdef array.array multiplicities = array.array('i', [])
    array.resize(multiplicities, lenUniqs)
    # multiplicities = [0] * lenUniqs
    cdef int idxIntoCmbo
    cdef int maxIdxCmbo
    cdef int curIdxCmbo
    cdef int idxIntoUniqs
    cdef int count        

    while idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo and idxIntoUniqs != lenUniqs:
        count = min(lstCntRpts[idxIntoUniqs], lenCmbo-idxIntoCmbo)
        maxIdxCmbo = idxIntoCmbo + count
        curIdxCmbo = idxIntoCmbo
        while curIdxCmbo < maxIdxCmbo: 
            cmboAsIdxUniqs[curIdxCmbo] = idxIntoUniqs
            curIdxCmbo += 1
        multiplicities[idxIntoUniqs] = count
        idxIntoCmbo  += count
        idxIntoUniqs += 1
    # print("multiplicities:", multiplicities)
    # print("cmboAsIdxUniqs:", cmboAsIdxUniqs)

    if idxIntoCmbo != lenCmbo:
        return

    cdef int x
    cdef int y
    while True:
        yield tuple(lstUniqs[idxUniqs] for idxUniqs in cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        for idxIntoCmbo in reversed(range(lenCmbo)):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            y = x + 1

            if y < lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] < lstCntRpts[y]:
                break
        else:
            return

        for idxIntoCmbo in range(idxIntoCmbo, lenCmbo):
            x = cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo]
            cmboAsIdxUniqs[idxIntoCmbo] = y
            multiplicities[x] -= 1
            multiplicities[y] += 1
            # print("# multiplicities:", multiplicities)


            while y != lenUniqs and multiplicities[y] == lstCntRpts[y]:
                y += 1

            if y == lenUniqs:
                break
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made some experiences when I rewrote some of the recipes of the itertools documentation as C extensions. I think I may have some insights that could help you.

#### Generator vs. Iterator class.

When you write pure Python code it's a tradeoff between speed (generator) and features (iterator).

The `yield` functions (known as generators) are for speed and generally they can be written without bothering about internal state. So it's less effort to write them and they are fast because Python just manages all the "state".

The reason generators are faster (or at least not slower) is mostly because:

- They implement the `__next__`-slot directly (typically `tp_iternext`) besides the `__next__`-method. In that case Python doesn't have to lookup the `__next__` method - that's essentially what makes it faster in the following example:

  ```
  from itertools import islice

  def test():
      while True:
          yield 1

  class Test(object):
      def __iter__(self):
          return self

      def __next__(self):
          return 1

  %timeit list(islice(test(), 1000))
  # 173 µs ± 2.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
  %timeit list(islice(Test(), 1000))
  # 499 µs ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```

  So it's almost 3 times faster just because generators directly populate the `__next__`-slot.
- A `yield`-function and the class have a state, but the `yield` function saves and loads the state much faster than you could with a class and attribute access:

  ```
  def test():
      i = 0
      while True:
          yield i
          i += 1

  class Test(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.val = 0

      def __iter__(self):
          return self

      def __next__(self):
          current = self.val
          self.val += 1
          return current

  %timeit list(islice(test(), 1000))
  # 296 µs ± 1.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  %timeit list(islice(Test(), 1000))
  # 1.22 ms ± 3.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```

  This time the class is already 4 times slower (compared to the almost 3 times, when no state was involved). That is a cumulative effect: so the more "state" you have, the slower the class variant will be.

So much for the `yield` vs. class approach. Note that the actual timing will depend on the kind of operations. For example if the actual code that is run when `next` is called is **slow** (i.e. `time.sleep(1)`) then there's almost no difference between generator and class!

#### Cython

If you want a cython iterator class that is **fast** it has to be a `cdef class`. Otherwise you don't get the really fast class. The reason is that only a `cdef class` creates an extension type that directly implements the `tp_iternext` field! I'll use IPythons `%%cython` to compile the code (so I don't have to include the setup):

```
%%cython

def test():
    while True:
        yield 1

class Test(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return 1

cdef class Test_cdef(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return 1

%timeit list(islice(test(), 1000))
# 113 µs ± 4.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit list(islice(Test(), 1000))
# 407 µs ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit list(islice(Test_cdef(), 1000))
# 62.8 µs ± 2.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The timings already show that the generator and basic class are faster than the pure Python equivalent, but their relative performance roughly stayed the same. However the `cdef class` variant beats both of them and that's mainly because the `tp_iternext` slot was used instead of just implementing the `__next__` method. (Inspect the Cython generated C code if you don't trust me :) )

However it's just 2 times faster than the Python generator, that's not bad but it's not exactly overwhelming. To get really amazing speedups, you'll need to find a way to express your program **without Python objects** (the less Python objects the more speedup). For example if you use a dictionary for storing the item and it's multiplicity you still store Python objects and any lookup has to be done using python dictionary methods - even if you can call them by C API function instead of having to look up the real methods:

```
%%cython

cpdef cython_count(items):
    cdef dict res = dict()
    for item in items:
        if item in res:
            res[item] += 1
        else:
            res[item] = 1
    return res

import random

def count(items):
    res = {}
    for item in items:
        if item in res:
            res[item] += 1
        else:
            res[item] = 1
    return res

l = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10000)]
%timeit cython_count(l)
# 2.06 ms ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit count(l)
# 3.63 ms ± 21.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

There's one catch here, you didn't use `collections.Counter` which has an optimized C code (at least in python-3) for this kind of operation:

```
from collections import Counter
%timeit Counter(l)
# 1.17 ms ± 41.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

A quick note here: Don't use `something in some_dict.keys()` because the `keys()` are list-like in Python2 and ony implement `O(n)` contains operations while `something in some_dict` is typically `O(1)` (both Pythons)! That will make things faster in both versions but especially on Python2:

```
def count2(items):
    res = {}
    for item in items:
        if item in res.keys():  # with "keys()"
            res[item] += 1
        else:
            res[item] = 1
    return res

# Python3
l = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10000)]
%timeit count(l)
# 3.63 ms ± 29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit count2(l)
# 5.9 ms ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Python2
l = [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(10000)]
%timeit count(l)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.59 ms per loop
%timeit count2(l)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.65 s per loop  <--- WHOOPS!!!
```

That shows that you can only hope for something like 3-4 times speedup with Cython (and C extensions) when you use python structures but even minor mistakes like using ".keys()" can cost you **much more** in terms of performance if used incorrectly.

#### Optimizing Cython

So what can you do if you want it faster? The answer is relativly easy: Create your own data structure based on C types instead of Python types.

That means you have to think about the design:

- What types do you want to support in your `uniqComb**`? Do you want integers (the examples say so, but I suppose you want arbitary Python objects).
- Do you want introspection from Python (like current state)? If you want it it would make sense to keep the multiplicity as python objects, but if you don't care you can save them as integer-like object instead of python objects.
- Do you need the objects passed to the `uniqComb**` function to be sortable? You used `sorted` but you could also use a `OrderedDict` and keep keys in the order of appearance instead of by numerical value.

The answers to these questions (these are only the question I immediatly asked myself, there are probably many more!) can help you decide which structure you can use internally. For example with Cython you can interface to C++ and you could use a [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) containing integer keys and integer values instead of a dictionary. It's sorted by default so you don't need to manually sort them yourself and you operate on native integers instead of Python objects. But you loose the ability to process arbitary python objects in your `uniqComb` and you need to know how to operate with C++ types in Cython. It could be amazingly fast though!

I don't go down that path because I assume you want to support arbitary orderable python types and I stick with the `Counter` as starting point but I'll save the multiplicities as integer `array.array`s instead of as `list`. Let's call it the "least invasive" optimization. It actually doesn't matter much in terms of performance if you use a `list` or the `array` for `lstCntRpts` and `multiplicities` because they aren't a bottleneck - but it's a bit faster and saves a bit memory **and** more importantly it shows how you can include homogeneous `array`s with cython:

```
%%cython

from cpython.list cimport PyList_Size  # (most) C API functions can be used with cython!

from array import array
from collections import Counter

cdef class uniqCmboClassIter:

    cdef list lstUniqs
    cdef Py_ssize_t lenUniqs
    cdef int[:] lstCntRpts   # memoryview
    cdef Py_ssize_t lenCmbo
    cdef list cmboAsIdxUniqs
    cdef int[:] multiplicities  # memoryview
    cdef Py_ssize_t idxIntoCmbo
    cdef Py_ssize_t idxIntoUniqs
    cdef bint stopIteration
    cdef Py_ssize_t x
    cdef Py_ssize_t y

    def __init__(self, lstItems, lenCmbo):
        dctCounter = Counter(lstItems)

        self.lstUniqs = sorted(dctCounter)
        self.lenUniqs = PyList_Size(self.lstUniqs)
        self.lstCntRpts = array('i', [dctCounter[item] for item in self.lstUniqs])

        self.lenCmbo        = lenCmbo
        self.cmboAsIdxUniqs = [None] * lenCmbo
        self.multiplicities = array('i', [0] * self.lenUniqs)
        self.idxIntoCmbo, self.idxIntoUniqs = 0, 0

        while self.idxIntoCmbo != self.lenCmbo and self.idxIntoUniqs != self.lenUniqs:
            count = min(self.lstCntRpts[self.idxIntoUniqs], self.lenCmbo-self.idxIntoCmbo)
            self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo : self.idxIntoCmbo + count] = [self.idxIntoUniqs] * count
            self.multiplicities[self.idxIntoUniqs] = count
            self.idxIntoCmbo += count
            self.idxIntoUniqs += 1
            # print("self.multiplicities:", self.multiplicities)
            # print("self.cmboAsIdxUniqs:", self.cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        if self.idxIntoCmbo != self.lenCmbo:
            return

        self.stopIteration = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

        return

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.stopIteration is True:
            raise StopIteration

        nextCmbo = tuple(self.lstUniqs[idxUniqs] for idxUniqs in self.cmboAsIdxUniqs)

        for self.idxIntoCmbo in reversed(range(self.lenCmbo)):
            self.x = self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo]
            self.y = self.x + 1

            if self.y < self.lenUniqs and self.multiplicities[self.y] < self.lstCntRpts[self.y]:
                break
        else:
            self.stopIteration = True
            return nextCmbo

        for self.idxIntoCmbo in range(self.idxIntoCmbo, self.lenCmbo):
            self.x = self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo]
            self.cmboAsIdxUniqs[self.idxIntoCmbo] = self.y
            self.multiplicities[self.x] -= 1
            self.multiplicities[self.y] += 1
            # print("# multiplicities:", multiplicities)

            while self.y != self.lenUniqs and self.multiplicities[self.y] == self.lstCntRpts[self.y]:
                self.y += 1

            if self.y == self.lenUniqs:
                break

        return nextCmbo
```

You actually didn't share your parameters for the timings but I tried it with some of mine:

```
from itertools import combinations

import random
import time

def create_values(maximum):

    vals = [random.randint(0, maximum) for _ in range(48)]
    print('length: ', len(vals))
    print('sorted values: ', sorted(vals))
    print('uniques: ', len(set(vals)))
    print('uniques in percent: {:%}'.format(len(set(vals)) / len(vals)))

    return vals

class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self._time = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(time.time() -  self._time)

vals = create_values(maximum=50)  # and 22 and 75 and 120
n = 6

with Timer():
    list(combinations(vals, n))

with Timer():
    list(uniqCmboClassIter(vals, n))

with Timer():
    list(uniqCmboClassIterOriginal(vals, n))

with Timer():
    list(uniqCmboYieldIterOriginal(vals, n))
```

> ```
> length:  48
> sorted values:  [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22]
> uniques:  21
> uniques in percent: 43.750000%
> 6.250450611114502
> 0.4217393398284912
> 4.250436305999756
> 2.7186365127563477
>
> length:  48
> sorted values:  [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 19, 19, 21, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 28, 29, 31, 31, 34, 34, 36, 36, 38, 39, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 47, 49, 50]
> uniques:  33
> uniques in percent: 68.750000%
> 6.2034173011779785
> 4.343803882598877
> 42.39261245727539
> 26.65750527381897
>
> length:  48
> sorted values:  [4, 4, 7, 9, 10, 14, 14, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 24, 26, 34, 36, 40, 42, 43, 43, 45, 46, 46, 52, 53, 58, 59, 59, 61, 63, 66, 68, 71, 72, 72, 75, 76, 80, 82, 82, 83, 84, 86, 86, 89, 92, 97, 99]
> uniques:  39
> uniques in percent: 81.250000%
> 6.859697341918945
> 10.437987327575684
> 104.12988543510437
> 65.25306582450867
>
> length:  48
> sorted values:  [4, 7, 11, 19, 24, 29, 32, 36, 49, 49, 54, 57, 58, 60, 62, 65, 67, 70, 70, 72, 72, 79, 82, 83, 86, 89, 89, 90, 91, 94, 96, 99, 102, 111, 112, 118, 120, 120, 128, 129, 129, 134, 138, 141, 141, 144, 146, 147]
> uniques:  41
> uniques in percent: 85.416667%
> 6.484673023223877
> 13.610010623931885
> 136.28764533996582
> 84.73834943771362
> ```

It definetly performs much better than the original approaches, actually several times faster with *just* type declarations. There's probably a lot more that could be optimized (disable bounds checking, using Python C API function calls, using unsigned integers or smaller integers if you know the "maximum" and "minimum" of your multiplicities, ...) - but the fact that it's not much slower than `itertools.combinations` even for 80% unique items and much faster than any original implementation is good enough for me. :-)

Comment: Wow! Please let me some time (days?) to digest all that information, but before I start would you be so kind to explain how do you know that you can use `PyList_Size` in `self.lenUniqs = PyList_Size(self.lstUniqs)`? I have used the search feature provided in the Cython documentation ( http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/search.html?q=PyList_Size ) with the result `Your search did not match any documents.`. Do for example  `sorted_list = PyEval_CallFunction(sorted, "(O)", iterable)` and `pool = PySequence_Tuple(sorted_list)` and so on work in Cython, too?

Comment: @Claudio Not all are supported (and most of the time Cython already uses the appropriate ones) but those defined in [Cython/Includes](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Cython/Includes) are avaiable. It can be messy to mix python types and C types though - so in general use them sparingly (for example `char *` instead of python strings, `PyObject *` instead of `object`). You need to import them like `from cpython.sequence cimport PySequence_Tuple`. In the above mentioned Includes are also C and C++ wrappers and additional ones can be imported from "extern".

Comment: Technically, all iterators have a `tp_iternext` slot, but the Python class and the naive non-extension-type Cython class have a `tp_iternext` that looks up the `__next__` method and calls it, while the generator and the `cdef class` have a `tp_iternext` that involves no method lookup. When the question was talking about writing C extension modules, I figured the questioner would be familiar with how to do that and know to use stuff like `tp_iternext`, but that was a bad assumption.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I am a greenhorn novice *(with solid but more than a decade old background related to programming)* when it comes to writing Python extension modules. But in spite of the fact that I am getting better at it every single day, I still don't understand what does it mean if one talk about `tp_iternext`  :( . I have expected that there must be something more to iterators than `__next__` and the explanation `MSeifert` provided about a `slot` (e.g. C code of `itertools.combinations()` does not have `__next__` or `__init__` only `combinations_next/new`) sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, but for (pure) python-classes it's just a level of indirection (I will correct the answer later).

Comment: @Claudio It's not necessarily important to know the slots explicitly. Think of them as "fast access" operations for C extension classes. For example [`tp_iternext`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_iternext) is explained alongside the other slots in ["C API: Type objects"](https://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#type-objects). It's roughly the equivalent to `__next__` in C extensions. But you don't need to set them explicitly with Cython (cython does that itself with `cdef` classes).

Comment: An explanation about `populating __next__` could be re-written for clarity and correctness. There's more going on under the hood — generator keeps state in a frame ('s locals) while a class that supports iteration protocol in instance ('s attributes).

Comment: @MSeifert : one more question comes to my mind after I mean I have gained some understanding from your explanations: how does it come that Python doesn't go the 'slot-way' for classes even if it is clear the class defines an iterator? Is there some advantage (as counter-weight to pure loss of execution speed) of doing it this way I am not aware of?

Comment: @Claudio Because you would lose the dynamic nature. For example you can reassign `__next__`: `Test.__next__ = lambda self: 2`. But as soon as you have a C extension class you can't reassign methods (actually it's possible, just not easy, but I don't think it works for special methods). Also normally it's just a small constant factor, remember that the overhead of the "slot looks up method" is _normally_ small compared to the operations done inside the `__next__` method. So it seldom is more than 2/3 times slower. Also generators are avaiable that mitigate that almost completly.

Comment: @MSeifert I was a bit wondering where the `%timeit` in your code examples came from (I plan to use them to improve the formulation of the question). One possible explanation is: you are using ipython, right? (neither idle nor bpython know about `timeit` without `from timeit import timeit` ...)

Comment: yes, it's the [IPython command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).

Comment: @MSeifert being in the process of trying to provide `unique.Combinations` on `pypi` have just seen there are `iteration_utilities` by you on `Github` and `pypi.python.org/pypi/iteration_utilities` where it would perfectly fit into. Would you like to provide this in Python itertools missing functionality in this package?

Comment: @Claudio I haven't thought about it yet. But feel free to make a PR or file an issue about it. I haven't thought how it could be best integrated there (the package currently doesn't support Cython extensions). :)

Answer (score 3):

When you write a generator function using `yield`, the overhead of saving off and restoring state is handled by the CPython internals (implemented in C). With `__iter__`/`__next__`, you have to manage saving and restoring state on each call. In CPython, Python level code is slower than C level built-ins so the extr Python level code involved in the state management (including stuff as simple as accessing attributes of `self` via `dict` lookups rather than loading local variables, with only array indexing overhead) ends up costing you a lot.

If you implement your own iterator protocol supporting type in a C extension module, you'll bypass this overhead; saving and restoring state should be a matter of a few C level variable accesses (with similar or lesser overhead compared to what Python generator functions incur, which is to say, very little). Effectively, that's what generator functions *are*, a C extension type that saves and restores the Python frame on each call to `tp_iternext` (the C level equivalent of `__next__`).

Comment: @Claudio: Without seeing the Cython code, I can't help you. Cython without type declarations rarely improves speed much, and even with declared types, it often misses easy optimization opportunities. The only way to do it "right" is to actually implement your class in C directly, using the Python C API. Or you can look at [how generator objects are actually implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/genobject.c#L773); they're done with `tp_iternext`, no special magic that another extension can't mimic.

Comment: Please check out the at the bottom with Cython code updated question.

Answer (score 2):

> The class with `__next__` version is the one suitable to be implemented
>   as a Python extension module because there is no equivalent of yield
>   in C, so it makes sense to find out how it could be improved in order
>   to perform comparable to the function with yield variant.

Write it in C already. The performance difference you're seeing is solely due to properties of the Python implementation that do not apply to the C extension module you're planning to write. Optimizations you could apply to the Python class would not be applicable to the C code.

For example, accessing instance variables is more expensive than accessing local variables in Python code, because instance variable access requires several dict lookups. Your C implementation will not require such dict lookups.

Comment: @Claudio: Did you just run Cython on your file with no modifications, or did you actually [generate an extension type](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html)?

Comment: I had run Cython with no modifications.