# Use numpy to get permutations of multiple lists' items

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, numpy

For example, if I have the following arrays:

```
arraya = ['z', 'q']
arrayb = ['t', 'f']
```

I'd like to use the items from each list to create 'pairs' and get the following output:

```
['zt', 'zf', 'qt', 'qf']
```

I know I can figure out a jury-rigged way to write a function that produces this result, but a prebuilt function would be better for my purposes.

Comment: Multiplication is mathematically not defined in vector operations, which makes me doubt there is a pre-built method for this. It looks like you are going to have to brute force this method due to it's rather specific needs.

Comment: What application are you trying to use this for that makes you think of this operation as "multiplication"? Are you trying to implement polynomial multiplication or something?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word choice. Bad on me. I more correctly meant something along the lines of array item permutations, using the items of two different lists. I`ll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close to a built-in as you'll be able to get.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(arraya, arrayb)]
['zt', 'zf', 'qt', 'qf']
```

Find the cartesian product of the 2 lists/arrays and then concatenate the product.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function for this, but you could use senderle's [cartesian_product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/190597) or pv's [cartesian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/190597) function. Which is faster may depend on your use case. Then the following yields the desired result:

```
In [40]: cartesian_product([['z', 'q'], ['t', 'f']]).ravel().view('<U2')
Out[40]: 
array(['zt', 'zf', 'qt', 'qf'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

These functions can be faster than using `itertools.product`. For example,

```
In [181]: x, y = np.arange(500), np.arange(500)

In [185]: %timeit cartesian_product([x, y])
1000 loops, best of 3: 797 µs per loop

In [184]: %timeit cartesian_product2([x, y])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit cartesian([x, y])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.71 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit np.array(list(IT.product(x, y)))
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop
```