# Pandas - combine two Series by all unique combinations

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following series:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
dtype: object

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

How can I merge them to create an empty dataframe with every possible combination of values, like this:

```
   letter  number
0       A       1
1       A       2
2       A       3
3       A       4
4       B       1
5       B       2
6       B       3
7       B       4
8       C       1
9       C       2
10      C       3
11      C       4
```

Comment: If you have a lot of data and need speed, check out this answer.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the 2 series are `s` and `s1`, use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which gives a *cartesian product of input iterables* :

```
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(s,s1)),columns=['letter','number'])
print(df)

    letter  number
0       A       1
1       A       2
2       A       3
3       A       4
4       B       1
5       B       2
6       B       3
7       B       4
8       C       1
9       C       2
10      C       3
11      C       4
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Pandas 1.2.0, there is a `how='cross'` option in `pandas.merge()` that produces the Cartesian product of the columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

letters = pd.DataFrame({'letter': ['A','B','C']})
numbers = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1,2,3,4]})

together = pd.merge(letters, numbers, how = 'cross')
```

```
   letter  number
0       A       1
1       A       2
2       A       3
3       A       4
4       B       1
5       B       2
6       B       3
7       B       4
8       C       1
9       C       2
10      C       3
11      C       4
```

As an additional bonus, this function makes it easy to do so with more than one column.

```py
letters = pd.DataFrame({'letterA': ['A','B','C'],
                        'letterB': ['D','D','E']})
numbers = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1,2,3,4]})

together = pd.merge(letters, numbers, how = 'cross')
```

```
   letterA letterB  number
0        A       D       1
1        A       D       2
2        A       D       3
3        A       D       4
4        B       D       1
5        B       D       2
6        B       D       3
7        B       D       4
8        C       E       1
9        C       E       2
10       C       E       3
11       C       E       4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 `Series` `s1` and `s2`.
you can do this:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=s1,columns=s2).unstack().reset_index()[["s1","s2"]]
```

It will give you the follow

```
   s1  s2
0   A   1
1   B   1
2   C   1
3   A   2
4   B   2
5   C   2
6   A   3
7   B   3
8   C   3
9   A   4
10  B   4
11  C   4
```

Comment: Just to add that this method requires that the series be named first, and the subsequent slicing ```[["s1", "s2"]]``` be done using the names of the series

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
  index = pd.MultiIndex
    .from_product(
      [
        ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
      ],
      names = ['letters', 'numbers']
    )
)
```

which results in a hierarchical structure:

```
letters numbers
      A       1
              2
              3
              4
      B       1
              2
              3
              4
      C       1
              2
              3
              4
```

and you can further call `.reset_index()` to get ungrouped results:

```
    letters numbers
0         A       1
1         A       2
2         A       3
3         A       4
4         B       1
5         B       2
6         B       3
7         B       4
8         C       1
9         C       2
10        C       3
11        C       4
```

(However I find @NickCHK's answer to be the best)