# Generate all combinations of an unknown number of variables

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, combinations

I have a list of variables, the number of which can change. Each variable has a lower limit, upper limit and an increment value. For example:

```
variables = {
   "a": [1, 10, 1],
   "b": [50, 200, 5],
   "c": [50, 300, 10]
}
```

Where for key "a", 1 is the lower limit, 10 is the upper limit and 1 is the increment amount.

```
"a" would go from 1 through 10, incrementing by 1
"b" would go from 50 through 200, incrementing by 5
"c" would go from 50 through 300, incrementing by 10
... there can be more or less such keys.
```

I need to create a list of all possible combinations of a, b and c, without hard coding nested loops, as there are an unknown number of variables/keys, and just cannot wrap my head around it. I'm using Python 3.7

The output would ideally be a table of combinations of each variable, perhaps comma separated values. For example.

```
a  b  c
x  y  z
x  y  z
x  y  z
x  y  z
```

However, anything will do, as long as I can collate the output into a format where each combination can be accessed as a set. Such as a list of tuples.

```
[
  (x, y, z)
  (x, y, z)
]
...
```

Comment: Can you post an output example

Comment: Sounds like you could use [this cartesian product implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/10293548) (obviously after creating the variable arrays)

Comment: I think you might look into the python itertools module.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, assuming:

```
variables = {
   "a": [1, 10, 1],
   "b": [50, 200, 5],
   "c": [50, 300, 10]
}
```

Then you can create an iterator using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
cartesian_product = product(*starmap(range, variables.values()))
```

Or, just to show you what starmap is doing:

```
cartesian_product = product(*(range(*v) for v in variables.values()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question here. Would the order of the keys in the source code definition of the dict be always reflected in the order of the tuple elements? Or do you suggest I use an OrderedDict?

Comment: @SidKhullar if you are using python version >= 3.7 then yes, it maintains insertion order. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: Some of my values are floats and this is causing a TypeError. Would you be able to suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [np.arange(v[0], v[1]+1, v[2]) for k,v in variables.items()]
np.array(np.meshgrid(*lst)).T.reshape(-1,len(lst))
```

Comment: Thank you. This appears to require a known number of variables.

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var=[]
for k in variables.keys():
  var.append(np.arange(variables[k][0],variables[k][1]+1,variables[k][2]))

np.array(np.meshgrid(var[0],var[1],var[2])).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

for combination I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays)

Comment: This appears to require a known number of variables.

Comment: you can use for loop for `np.arange`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


a = np.arange(1, 10, 1)
b = np.arange(50, 200, 5)
c = np.arange(50,300,10)

results = itertools.product(a, b, c)
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 50, 50)
(1, 50, 60)
...
...
(9, 195, 270)
(9, 195, 280)
(9, 195, 290)
```

Comment: @SidKhullar if that was helpful, will by nice if you accept my answer :)

Comment: This works, great, thanks, but how do I make this portion dynamic? ```results = itertools.product(a, b, c)```; specially the 'a, b, c'?

Comment: @SidKhullar by `dynamic` you mean set different variables numbers or different amount of arrays?

Comment: why `numpy` here? Just use `range`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you share a code snippet I could try out please?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I mean, we have an unknown number of variables, and that code segment specifically mentions each variable. Is there a way to make it work with an unknown number of variables or keys in a dict?

Comment: @SidKhullar sure, posted a quick answer