# In Python, how can I combine a set of tuples from a list of given tuples without using itertools?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list as follows:

`[(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6,)]`

I know it's very easy to combine the list of tuples by using itertools.

`(1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6)`

But how can I solve it without using itertools?

Comment: Despite the nice answers below, you should have a look at [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608701/803359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly generic approach with a series of loops over the input:

```
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6,)]

result = [tuple([l]) for l in lst[0]]
for l in lst[1:]:
    out = []
    for r in result:
        for i in range(len(l)):
            out.append((*r, l[i]))
    result = out

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [(x, y, 6) for x in (1, 2) for y in (3, 4, 5)]
```

Also see [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) for more general solutions

Comment: Brilliant! Any alternatives without using list comprehension?

Comment: you can use nested loop?

Comment: if you are looking for a complicated way check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cartesian-product-of-any-number-of-sets/.

Comment: another idea, define cartesian product or copy paste from another site and apply reduce to the list `reduce( cartesian, [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6,)] )`

Answer (score 0):

```
def product(pools):
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    return result

product([(1,2,3),(4,5),(6,)])
[[1, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6], [3, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: While the code seems obvious for many, please add some explanation to your only code answer. Also note that you are not returning  tuples.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26294560)