# Cartesian product of successive pairs in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose that each product has different versions that change over time, and I have a data set of time observations with the product id, version id and other data

[image]

I am interested in the Cartesian product of the *indices* of successive versions. i.e. the cartesian products of the indices  of `version_1` and `version_2`,  `version_2` and `version_3` and  `version_3` and `version_4`.

For example the cartesian product of `version_1` and `version_2` is: (0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (0,4), (1,4), (2,4), `version_2` and `version_3` is (3,5), (3,6), (3,7), (4,5), (4,6), (4,7), etc. Ideally I would like two arrays: one of the left indices and one of the right.

Any hints as to how this can be done efficiently using numpy rather than manually looping which is very slow.

Comment: Here are the same questions as you and [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays).

Comment: Thanks but I am interested in the cartesian product of successive versions only, rather than the cartesian product of all versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to do is to manually get the version order for each product, looping through the successive versions and then getting the indices of the cartesian product.

```
def cartesian_product(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    return np.tile(x, len(y)), np.repeat(y, len(x))

unique_product_ids = np.unique(product_ids)
unique_countries = np.unique(countries)

indices_left_list = []
indices_right_list = []

for product_id in unique_product_ids:
    current_product_versions = product_versions[product_ids == product_id]

    _, indexes = np.unique(current_product_versions, return_index=True)
    unique_versions_in_order = [current_product_versions[index] for index in sorted(indexes)]

    for country in unique_countries:
        for version_left, version_right in zip(unique_versions_in_order, unique_versions_in_order[1:]):
            indices_left, indices_right = cartesian_product(
                np.flatnonzero((countries == country) & (product_ids == product_id) & (product_versions == version_left)),
                np.flatnonzero((countries == country) & (product_ids == product_id) & (product_versions == version_right))
            )
            indices_left_list.append(indices_left)
            indices_right_list.append(indices_right)


indices_left = np.concatenate(indices_left_list)
indices_right = np.concatenate(indices_right_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({'version': ['version_1', 'version_1', 'version_1', 'version_2', 'version_2', 'version_3', 'version_3', 'version_3', 'version_4']})

df.version = df.version.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
df = df.reset_index().groupby('version')['index'].apply(list).rename('versions').reset_index()
df['versions_shift'] = df['versions'].shift(-1, fill_value=[[]])
df['cartesian'] = df.apply(lambda x: itertools.product(x['versions'], x['versions_shift']), axis=1)
df['cartesian'] = df['cartesian'].apply(lambda x: list(zip(*x)))
df.drop(['version', 'versions', 'versions_shift'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
                                  cartesian
0  [(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2), (3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4)]
1  [(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), (5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7)]
2                    [(5, 6, 7), (8, 8, 8)]
3                                        []
```