# All possible concatenations of two tensors in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have two tensors `S` and `T` defined as:

```
S = torch.rand((3,2,1))
T = torch.ones((3,2,1))
```

We can think of these as containing batches of tensors with shapes `(2, 1)`. In this case, the batch size is `3`.

I want to concatenate all possible pairings between batches. A single concatenation of batches produces a tensor of shape `(4, 1)`. And there are `3*3` combinations so ultimately, the resulting tensor `C` must have a shape of `(3, 3, 4, 1)`.

One solution is to do the following:

```
for i in range(S.shape[0]):
  for j in range(T.shape[0]):
    C[i,j,:,:] = torch.cat((S[i,:,:],T[j,:,:]))
```

But the for loop doesn't scale well to large batch sizes. Is there a PyTorch command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any command out-of-the-box that does such operation. However, you can pull it off in a straightforward way using a single matrix multiplication.

---

The trick is to construct a tensor containing all pairs of batch elements by starting from already stacked `S,T` tensor. Then by multiplying it with a properly chosen `mask` tensor... In this method, keeping track of shapes and dimension sizes is essential.

1. The stack is given by (notice the reshape, we essentially flatten the batch elements from `S` and `T` into a single batch axis on `ST`):

   ```
   >>> ST = torch.stack((S, T)).reshape(6, 2)
   >>> ST
   tensor([[0.7792, 0.0095],
           [0.1893, 0.8159],
           [0.0680, 0.7194],
           [1.0000, 1.0000],
           [1.0000, 1.0000],
           [1.0000, 1.0000]]
   # ST.shape = (6, 2)
   ```
2. You can retrieve all `(S[i], T[j])` pairs using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

   ```
   >>> indices = torch.tensor(list(product(range(0, 3), range(3, 6))))
   tensor([[0, 3],
           [0, 4],
           [0, 5],
           [1, 3],
           [1, 4],
           [1, 5],
           [2, 3],
           [2, 4],
           [2, 5]])
   # indices.shape = (9, 2)
   ```
3. From there, we construct one-hot-encodings of the indices using [`torch.nn.functional.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html):

   ```
   >>> mask = one_hot(indices).float()
   tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]],

           [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

           [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

           [[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]],

           [[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

           [[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

           [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]],

           [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

           [[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
            [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]])
   # mask.shape = (9, 2, 6)
   ```
4. Finally, we compute the matrix multiplication and reshape it to the final form:

   ```
   >>> (mask@ST).reshape(3, 3, 4, 1)
   tensor([[[[0.7792],
             [0.0095],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.7792],
             [0.0095],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.7792],
             [0.0095],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]]],


           [[[0.1893],
             [0.8159],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.1893],
             [0.8159],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.1893],
             [0.8159],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]]],


           [[[0.0680],
             [0.7194],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.0680],
             [0.7194],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]],

            [[0.0680],
             [0.7194],
             [1.0000],
             [1.0000]]]])
   ```

<sub>I initially went with [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html): `torch.einsum('bf,pib->pif', ST, mask)`. But, later realized than that `bf,pib->pif` reduces nicely to a simple [`torch.Tensor.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) operation if we switch the two operands: *i.e.* with `pib,bf->pif` (subscript `b` is reduced in the *middle*).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, if the batch size is big (in my case the tensors S and T both have size (2000,40,1), then the system crashes when we create the mask because it requires too much memory). Is there a way to extract the relevant indices from the stacked tensor without the mask?

Comment: I will have a look at it with `torch.gather`, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy something called np.meshgrid is used.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608701/3259896

So in pytorch, it would be

```
torch.stack(
torch.meshgrid(x, y)
).T.reshape(-1,2)
```

Where x and y are your two lists. You can use any number. x, y , z, etc.

And then you reshape it to the number of lists you use.

So if you used three lists, use `.reshape(-1,3)`, for four use `.reshape(-1,4)`, etc.

So for 5 tensors, use

```
torch.stack(
torch.meshgrid(a, b, c, d, e)
).T.reshape(-1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `torch.repeat_interleave` and `Tensor.repeat` to reproduce a for loop.

For instance I have

```py
>>> tensor_1 # shape(3, 4)
tensor([[0.1164, 0.6336, 0.7037, 0.1360],
        [0.9316, 0.9569, 0.4108, 0.5415],
        [0.6325, 0.3159, 0.3307, 0.0700]])
>>> tensor_2 # shape(2, 4)
tensor([[0.1687, 0.3315, 0.1523, 0.1123],
        [0.1792, 0.8289, 0.7350, 0.2479]])
```

To get the result of

```py
for i in range(tensor_1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(tensor_2.shape[0]):
        torch.cat([tensor_1[i, ...], tensor_2[j, ...]], dim=0) # shape (8, )
```

We can do

```py
b, h = tensor_1.shape
e, h = tensor_2.shape

result = torch.cat(
    [torch.repeat_interleave(tensor_1, repeats=e, dim=0), tensor_2.repeat(b, 1), ]
    , dim=-1,
).reshape(b, e, 2 * h)
```

(`torch.repeat_interleave` is for the outer for loop, which repeats `tensor_1` `e` times in an element-wise manner. `Tensor.repeat` is for the inner for loop, repeats `tensor_2` `b` times as a whole), which gives

```py
>>> result
tensor([[[0.1164, 0.6336, 0.7037, 0.1360, 0.1687, 0.3315, 0.1523, 0.1123],
         [0.1164, 0.6336, 0.7037, 0.1360, 0.1792, 0.8289, 0.7350, 0.2479]],

        [[0.9316, 0.9569, 0.4108, 0.5415, 0.1687, 0.3315, 0.1523, 0.1123],
         [0.9316, 0.9569, 0.4108, 0.5415, 0.1792, 0.8289, 0.7350, 0.2479]],

        [[0.6325, 0.3159, 0.3307, 0.0700, 0.1687, 0.3315, 0.1523, 0.1123],
         [0.6325, 0.3159, 0.3307, 0.0700, 0.1792, 0.8289, 0.7350, 0.2479]]])
```