# Check if there exists a value in each of 3 numpy arrays, that are within an interval of x?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have 3 `numpy` arrays. It could be more than 3 arrays, however.

```py
import numpy as np
INTERVAL = 2
array1 = np.array([1,5,10,15,20,25,30])
array2 = np.array([1,10,50,100,150,200,250,300])
array3 = np.array([3,8,12])
```

For a given set of elements to match in the above arrays, each element must be within `INTERVAL` of each other. The actual index position of the elements in the array do not matter in the comparison. Order is not guaranteed. It is about any element at any position in the arrays are each within `INTERVAL` of each other.

Example matches that would be returned from the above 3 arrays:

```
Example#1
array1 : 1
array2 : 1
array3 : 3

Example#2
array1 : 10
array2 : 10
array3 : 8

Example#3
array1 : 10
array2 : 10
array3 : 12
```

Bonus points :

In the event where there could be multiple matches with the same elements, only return the one with the lowest sum. For example, `Example#2` and `Example#3` share elements, but `Example#2` & `Example#1` should be returned and not `Example#3`

Any suggestions on how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cartesian product using `np.meshgrid` (credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208118/17769815) for the Cartesian product code). Then, you can use `np.where` to extract combinations that meet the difference constraint:

```py
product = np.array(np.meshgrid(array1, array2, array3)).T.reshape(-1,3)
result = product[np.where(product.max(axis=1) - product.min(axis=1) <= INTERVAL)]

repr(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
array([[ 1,  1,  3],
       [10, 10,  8],
       [10, 10, 12]])
```