# Python Numpy: Find sorted combinations between elements of each row

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[557, 207, 521, 103, 411],
                [452, 255,  98, 412, 425],
                [384, 221, 587, 355, 413],
                [571,  24, 138, 414, 460],
                [368, 140,  70,  55, 415]])
```

How can I find all the sorted combinations (ascendingly or descendingly) between the elements of each row. For example, `np.array([103, 255, 355, 414, 415])` would be a valid combination as well as `np.array([557, 452, 384, 138, 70])`. Ideally, I would like to also find combinations which may skip a row, but still contain a given minimum number of elements. For instance, if we want combinations of at least 4 elements, then `np.array([103, np.nan, 355, 414, 415])` would also be valid.

For now, I have been using the following method:

1. Compute combinations by using the meshgrid approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays)

```
height = arr.shape[0]
arr2 = np.hstack((arr, np.full((height ,1), np.nan)))
combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(*arr2 )).T.reshape(-1, height)
```

```
>>> combinations

array([[557., 452., 384., 571., 368.],
       [557., 255., 384., 571., 368.],
       [557.,  98., 384., 571., 368.],
       ...,
       [ nan, 412.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan, 425.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

2. Justify combinations to the left by using the `justify`  function taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array).

```
justified_array = justify(combinations , invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1)

>>> justified_array 

array([[557., 452., 384., 571., 368.],
       [557., 255., 384., 571., 368.],
       [557.,  98., 384., 571., 368.],
       ...,
       [412.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [425.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

3. Determine sorted combinations.

```
diff_comb = np.diff(justified_array)
nan_diff_mask = np.isnan(diff_comb)
sorted_mask = np.all((diff_comb > 0) | nan_diff_mask, axis=1) | \
              np.all((diff_comb < 0) | nan_diff_mask, axis=1)
combinations = combinations[sorted_mask]
```

4. Finally, determine combinations which contain enough defined values

```
N = 4 # Minimum number of elements required for a combination to be valid
enough_elements = np.sum(~np.isnan(combinations ), axis=1) >= N
valid_combinations = combinations[enough_elements]
```

Final results:

```
>>> valid_combinations 

array([[557., 452.,  nan, 414., 368.],
       [557., 425.,  nan, 414., 368.],
       [521., 452.,  nan, 414., 368.],
       ...,
       [103., 255., 413., 460.,  nan],
       [103., 412., 413., 460.,  nan],
       [411., 412., 413., 460.,  nan]])
```

Even though it works, this brute force method is not very efficient as it computes all the possible combinations at the beginning by using the `meshgrid`  function. Moreover, it simply doesn't work for larger arrays, as the number of combinations increases exponentially. I would like to work with arrays up to several dozens of rows.

I'm sure there are several other, much more effective ways of doing this using numpy. Any idea?