# How to multiply array elements for nth arrays in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make method for creating array from nth arrays in Python . I have looked Numpy but the method seems not suit my requirement.
The following is my code works in javascript.
numArr = [[1],[12],[22],[31,32,33],[41,42]] , the result will be
[1,12,22,31,41],[1,12,22,31,42],[1,12,22,32,41],[1,12,22,32,42],[1,12,22,33,41],[1,12,22,33,42]

```
for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    tempNumArr = new Array(totalNumArr.length * numArr[i].length);
    for (var j = 0; j < totalNumArr.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < numArr[i].length; k++) {
        tempNumArr[j * numArr[i].length + k] = new Array();
        if (i !== 0)
          tempNumArr[j * numArr[i].length + k] = totalNumArr[j].slice();

        tempNumArr[j * numArr[i].length + k].push(numArr[i][k]);
      }
    }
    totalNumArr = tempNumArr;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a product of arrays

```
import itertools

ls = [[1],[12],[22],[31,32,33],[41,42]]

print([p for p in itertools.product(*ls)])
```

(gives a list of tuples, but can be easily changed to give list of lists instead)

Comment: How to return in array type instead of list ?

Comment: @AnsonChan numpy array?

Comment: You can use `np.array([p for p in itertools.product(*ls)])`

Answer (score 0):

A maybe not so obvious but pure Numpy solution, where the result is a 2D Numpy array, would be:

```py
import numpy as np

num_arr = [[1], [12], [22], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42]]
result = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(*num_arr)).reshape(len(num_arr), -1).T
print(result)
# >>> [[ 1 12 22 31 41]
#      [ 1 12 22 31 42]
#      [ 1 12 22 32 41]
#      [ 1 12 22 32 42]
#      [ 1 12 22 33 41]
#      [ 1 12 22 33 42]]
```

It uses [numpy.meshgrid()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and follows [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608701/7395592) to a similar question.

What happens in detail is the following:

1. With `np.meshgrid(*num_arr)` we create a list of 5 Numpy arrays, each holding 1×1×1×3×2 values. The *n*-th array holds the combinations of the *n*-th sublist of `num_arr` along the *n*-th axis and is repeated as necessary along the other axes. To make this clear, the first array contains `[[[[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]]]]`, the penultimate array contains `[[[[[31, 31], [32, 32], [33, 33]]]]]`, and the last array contains `[[[[[41, 42], [41, 42], [41, 42]]]]]`.
2. With `np.asarray()`, we convert the 5-element list of 1×1×1×3×2 Numpy arrays to one 5×1×1×1×3×2 Numpy array.
3. With `reshape(len(num_arr), -1)`, we reshape the combinations into a 2D Numpy array. As a result, due to the peculiar arrangement of values in the array (see step 1), we get a 5×6 Numpy array, where each *column* holds one combination of values.
4. As we (presumably) want each combination in a *row* of the resulting array instead, we transpose the result of step 3 with `.T` to get the final result: a 6×5 Numpy array, where each row holds one combination of values.